# How to use VLOOKUP function in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am very very new to Excel
I have two sheets
Sheet 1

```
Country PMU             Cluster
A       Asia            Mercury
B       Australia       Venus
C       North America   Jupiter
```

All the countries and continents are unique here
In sheet 2
I have

```
CountryCode Country  PMU  Cluster
123         A
234         A
453         B
235         C
```

1 country can have multiple codes
I have to take the PMU and Cluster and merge it with Sheet 2 , sheet 2 will have an additional column of Country Code.
Any help is very much apprciated.

Comment: Since you have multiple country codes per country, it would much easier to add the Continent to sheet 2. That would be a simple vlookup formula. If you really want to update sheet1, then you need to look into other ways such as index/match or vlookup after data manipulation.

Comment: Can you explain how to add continent to sheet 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing my answer per your edits.

I'm just doing this on a single sheet but you can easily adapt by pointing to your other sheet for your lookup array.

Here is the formula for cell G2:

```
    ==VLOOKUP($F2,$A:$C,2,FALSE)
```

Here is the formula for cell H2:

```
    =VLOOKUP($F2,$A:$C,3,FALSE)
```

Drag your formulas down and you're done. Vlookup formulas are very useful I recommend looking up how they work as someone else could better explain than I. Basically, you are looking up a value (column F) in an array (columns A,B,C) and returning a column index (B = 2, C = 3, etc) for a match. Lastly, you are looking for an approximate (TRUE) or exact (FALSE) match. Almost always use FALSE.

Also, look up cell references and how to lock them (ie, how $ signs rules vary). That way you can easily drag formulas across and keep your lookup value and array the same.

[image]

Comment: Hey, your formula works well with the same sample data , however when I am trying to replicate on mine , only one value is coming and rest is coming as NA, I have edited my question. Can you please check once and guide me as to what to do? I am really unable to figure this out :(

Comment: @coder_bg Give me a minute and I'll modify replace my answer.

Comment: YESS THIS WORKED!!! I understood the concept more now. THANKS A LOT!!! Have upvoted and ticked your answer :))

Comment: Replace false in vlookup with 0 as it is less typing...